# Finding full QR decomposition from reduced QR

Tags: math, matrix, statistics

What's the best way to find additional orthonormal columns of Q? I have computed the reduced QR decomposition already, but need the full QR decomposition.

I assume there is a standard approach to this, but I've been having trouble finding it.

You might wonder why I need the full Q matrix. I'm using it to apply a constraint matrix for "natural" splines to a truncated power series basis expansion. I'm doing this in Java, but am looking for a language-independent answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Successively add columns to Q in the following way:

1. Pick a vector not already in the span of Q
2. Orthogonalize it with respect to the columns of Q
3. Add the orthogonalized vector as a new column of Q.
4. Add a row of zeros to the bottom of R

For reference, see [these illustrative albeit mathematical lecture notes](http://www.ugrad.cs.ubc.ca/~cs402/handouts/handout07.pdf)

Just in case, the process of "orthogonalization" of a new vector is an old technique called the Gram-Schmidt process, and there is a [variant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process#Numerical_stability) which is numerically stable.

Comment: Thanks! I eventually figured out I needed to use Gram-Schmidt.